# How far do you go with Mobile First Responsive Design?

Tags: mobile, user-interface, responsive-design

I'm retro-fitting a website for Mobile First Responsive Design (MFRD).  My question is - how far do you go with the "Mobile First" part?.

For example - on the homepage I plan on having a list of upcoming events, say 4 or 5.  On the mobile version I thought 2 would be enough to save screen real-estate.  Should I load the other events in dynamically for the larger views, or should I just hide them since it will only be a few elements anyway?

Loading them dynamically for larger sizes means I have to attach an event to the window resize which typically gets fired every pixel.  Even though I can offset that with Timeout, that's still a lot of client side checking is it not (even though it's not like users are constantly resizing their browsers).

I mean, even though you're designing for mobile first, you also have to consider the larger sizes right?  Obviously larger JavaScript libraries and other assets that are needed for larger only you want to pull in later and not load for mobile - but how crazy do you want to get with the bandwidth saving?

Answer (score 0):

What is the target market for the website?  Are you making a completely responsive website that encapsulates smartphone to desktop?  Or are you just concentrating on smartphone to tablet?

Mobile First really just means start your styling and content views at the smallest form factor and work up as the device dimensions get bigger.  HTML, CSS (media queries) and jQuery all play a part to expand the UI and manipulate (show/hide) content elements as the browser gets bigger.

Take a look at [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/), their responsive layout is one of the most extensive I have seen so far, it will give you an idea of how far you can take the MFRD or DARL (Device Agnostic Responsive Layout) methodologies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I understand the basic concepts behind "mobile first" - but from my understanding designing for mobile first is not just about designing for the small screen, but also optimizing for small devices (bandwidth, etc.).  I was looking for more of "what's the trade off" between bandwidth optimized and ease of programming for multiple devices.  Since the entire sidebar of Smashing Mag is loaded on smaller devices (even though it's hidden) can it be truly considered "mobile first"?

Comment: If a website is extremely heavy in bandwidth (e.g. - large datasets) then stuffing it into a mobile website is probably not the best idea.  If lazy load is required on more than one or two key features of website then a rethinking of the business model might be needed. You could look at what the average bandwidth usage is for a smartphone per month and determine the average amount of data you will send to the browser.  If the website is destroying the smartphones bandwidth usage then you need to rethink your target market and/or device(s). There are so many factors to this question.